VBA code for pulling in data for a list of headers from other sheet. And compiling a dataset by repeating the same for all sheets within a workbook
I have a workbook with over 90 sheets. Each sheet contains data for respective request Number (customer). Each sheet contains a row 1= key (Profile Section &"_"& Header), row 2= Profile section, Row 3= Header within each section, and then data rows for request number (1 or more rows). We need to compile the data for specified headers from all the tabs and compile together in a dataset.

I have a list of headers in the dashboard sheet (Table name "Parameters"). This is copied to as column headers for tab "Customer Dataset".

Currently, i have written the code for deleting the old sheet "Customer Dataset" and creating new sheet, with updated list of required headers (flexibility of updating headers) .

Look for the header key in row 3 of "Customer Dataset" and match it with row 1 of first customer sheet, and pull the column values in tab "Customer dataset". Look for other header and repeat the same. So we will have customer data rows for the 1 customer for all specified headers.

Now, this exercise needs to be repeated across all other customer tabs and the data needs to be appended in the sheet "Customer Dataset"
Any other suggested approach is also highly appreciated. For testing purpose I am currently running the code only across 3 sheets.





Pulling selected parameters data in one worksheet
Sub PullData()
Dim wbcompile As Workbook
Dim wssrc, wsdest As Worksheet
Dim ws_Count As Integer
Dim Par_Count As Integer
Dim Par As ListObject

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wbcompile = ActiveWorkbook
    wbcompile.Worksheets("Customer Dataset").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets.Add After:=wbcompile.Worksheets("Dashboard")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Customer Dataset"
    Set wsdest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Customer Dataset")
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    Set Par = Worksheets("Dashboard").ListObjects("Parameters")
    Par_Count = Par.ListColumns(2).Range.Count
    Application.Goto Reference:="Parameters"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Customer Dataset").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Debug.Print Par_Count
    ws_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 2
    Debug.Print ws_Count

End Sub


Is your ultimate search then to find a column on each customer sheet ("NFP_ONB_*") where the first three rows of a column match the first three rows in a column on the Customer Datasheet? Then you'd grab that column from the customer sheet and append it to the bottom of the Datasheet?

Something like this (compiled but not tested):
Sub PullData()
    Dim wbcompile As Workbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, wsPar As Worksheet '<< every variable needs a type
    Dim loPar As ListObject, arr

    Set wbcompile = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsPar = wbcompile.Worksheets("Dashboard")
    Set loPar = wsPar.ListObjects("Parameters")
    arr = loPar.DataBodyRange.Value 'get parameters as array
    
    Set wsDest = wbcompile.Worksheets("Customer Dataset")
    wsDest.Cells.Clear
    'flip the array and place on summary sheet
    wsDest.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 2), UBound(arr, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    
    For Each wsSrc In wbcompile.Worksheets
        'extract from this sheet?
        If wsSrc.Name <> wsDest.Name And wsSrc.Name <> wsPar.Name Then
            ExtractData wsSrc, wsDest
        End If
    Next wsSrc
End Sub

Sub ExtractData(wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet)
    Dim lrSrc As Long, nextRowDest As Long, c As Range, m
    
    lrSrc = LastOccupiedRow(wsSrc)  'last row of data on source sheet
    If lrSrc = 3 Then Exit Sub      'no data
    nextRowDest = LastOccupiedRow(wsDest) + 1 'next row to paste to on summary sheet
    'loop over headers in row1 of source sheet
    For Each c In wsSrc.Range("A1", wsSrc.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        m = Application.Match(c.Value, wsDest.Rows(3), 0) 'match on summary sheet row 3?
        If Not IsError(m) Then 'got a match?
            'copy row 4 to last row to the summary sheet
            wsSrc.Range(wsSrc.Cells(4, c.Column), wsSrc.Cells(lrSrc, c.Column)).Copy _
                   wsDest.Cells(nextRowDest, m)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

Function LastOccupiedRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedRow = f.Row
End Function


This worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.

I have to compare about~1200 header values for 90 tabs each. The code is taking a lot of time. Is there a way to speed it up?

If you're able to share an example workbook I can take a look at improving the run-time.    You can replace any sensitive data with placeholder text if needed.   Let me know if you can share one, and I'll drop my email here.

I can share the file with you. Let me know your email ID.

Shared on mail. Please check.

Replied to your mail

You have a good start and can benefit from the example below, plus some other helpful tips.

Always use Option Explicit in your code. You may be doing this, but it's always a good reminder.
Avoid using Select - it's very rare that you have to use it, so here's a good explanation.
Even if the variable name is long-ish, use natural-sounding names that describe exactly what data the variable holds.
Avoid using numbers or strings that are repeated in multiple places in your code. If you ever have to change those values, it's a pain and you can easily miss one. So use constants.

For your example, I created a few module-global constants that can make it much simpler in the future to change or update.
Option Explicit

Const DASHBOARD_WS_NAME As String = "Dashboard"
Const CUSTOMER_DATASET_WS_NAME As String = "Customer Dataset"
Const CUSTOMER_DATA_PREFIX As String = "NFP_ONB*"


Break up your code into the smallest logical blocks by creating other Subs and Functions.

Here, I've created your "main" routine that holds the overall structure of your logic. If you keep it shorter by creating other functions, you can then get a much easier sense of what you're trying to do:
Sub NewPullData()
    Dim dashboardWS As Worksheet
    Set dashboardWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(DASHBOARD_WS_NAME)
    
    Const PARAM_TBL_NAME As String = "ParametersTable"
    Dim paramTbl As ListObject
    Set paramTbl = dashboardWS.ListObjects(PARAM_TBL_NAME)
    
    Dim datasetWS As Worksheet
    Set datasetWS = CreateDataset(paramTbl)
    
    PullCustomerData datasetWS, CUSTOMER_DATA_PREFIX
End Sub


Next, the CreateDataset function works to manage all the setup of that worksheet in a single, manageable location.

Function CreateDataset(ByRef paramTbl As ListObject) As Worksheet
    '--- creates a clean Dataset worksheet, deleting an existing
    '    sheet if necessary
    Dim datasetWS As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set datasetWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CUSTOMER_DATASET_WS_NAME)
    If Not datasetWS Is Nothing Then
        '--- disable alerts to prevent the popup question
        Dim prevAlertsState As Boolean
        prevAlertsState = Application.DisplayAlerts
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        datasetWS.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = prevAlertsState
    End If
    Set datasetWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(DASHBOARD_WS_NAME))
    datasetWS.Name = CUSTOMER_DATASET_WS_NAME
    
    '--- grab the parameters from the dashboard table
    '    and create the header columns for the dataset
    paramTbl.DataBodyRange.Copy
    datasetWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    '--- let's make it nice to read
    With datasetWS
        Dim numCols As Long
        numCols = .Cells(1, .Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        Dim headerRows As Range
        Set headerRows = .Range("A1").Resize(3, numCols)
        With headerRows
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
            .Font.Bold = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End With
    
    '--- return this sheet
    Set CreateDataset = datasetWS
End Function


And here's a framework to loop over your customer data sheets for you to fill in:

Sub PullCustomerData(ByRef datasetWS As Worksheet, ByVal sheetPrefix As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like sheetPrefix Then
            '--- put your logic to determine which column(s) you
            '    want to copy here
        End If
    Next we
End Sub


Thank you for this solution. I tried it and it looks great. Have a few questions-

Sub PullCustomerData has SheetPrefix defined as an input variable, however we globally defined "Customer_Data_Prefix as the variable. They should be same right?



For the last section of Sub PullCustomerData: The column logic is that for the headers in row 3 of tab "Customer Dataset" which is also column 3 of parameters table, are to be matched in the individual customer tab (row 1) and the corresponding number of data rows needs to be pulled for those respective headers and pasted in the "Customer dataset" tab. The logic needs to be looped across all the tabs and append the data rows in the customer dataset tab.



Is there a way that while pulling values from individual tab, I could assign the values to a 2D array with number of rows being #datarows +1 (for the headers) and the number of columns being count of parameters. This would help in pasting one tabs values for all parameters together in the customer dataset tab, instead of jumping between the tabs for matching individual header and copy pasting its values.



For ex: within the SS attached originally, we have list of 14 parameters (col K in first SS). In the second ss we see data populated till max of 4 rows for these parameter list (col B has 4 rows, others less). So while running through this tab, the 2 d array will be of size (4+1, 14), with first row as headers & rest with the data. And then copy pasting these values in customer dataset tab. Now looping to another customer tab, following same procedure & then pasting it below the previously pasted values in the "Customer Dataset" tab. I believe that would reduce the code run time.

